# How to save image as jpg or png using timthumb.php resizing API

Tags: php, image

I am using popular [timthumb.php](http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/source/browse/trunk/timthumb.php) to resize images. i am successfully able to change height and width of image but whenever i do "save as" by default it saves as php..

for example, if you try to save the image present at
http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/demo/timthumb-basic/timthumb.php?src=castle1.jpg&w=400 it saves as a file with extension php..

how do i force to save it as png/jpg? i know the mime type is image/jpg or image/png .... all i want is the image should save as png or jpg by default... kindly help

Comment: What browser? Chrome try to save it as a jpeg image.

Answer (score 1):

Timthumb doesn't have "save as" option (see this reply http://o7.no/biJTYD on the developer blog http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/11/timthumb-hints-tips/). Timthumbs saves the processed image with the same format as the source image.

I succeded in forcing a "save as jpg" when source is "png" with the followingwork around (near line 742). You may arrange other conversions working on the if-then-else chain.

```
if(preg_match('/^image\/(?:jpg|jpeg)$/i', $mimeType)){ 
        $imgType = 'jpg';
        imagejpeg($canvas, $tempfile, $quality); 
} else if(preg_match('/^image\/png$/i', $mimeType)){ 
        // ***************WORKAROUND STARTS HERE****************
        //$imgType = 'png';
        //imagepng($canvas, $tempfile, floor($quality * 0.09));
        $imgType = 'jpg';
        imagejpeg($canvas, $tempfile, $quality);
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested but you can add an extra header to line 1195 under:

```
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '";');
```

Answer (score 0):

i simply use timthumb.php from this URL http://timthumb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/timthumb.php
and when i click on save as, default file name is "Imagename.php.jpeg". and can able to change name before ".jpeg". may this will help you.

i am using Firefox on ubuntu 10.4.

enjoy